# I can't seem to load the dplyr package, apparently I need to update something but I have updated R and the package itself and nothing seems to work

Tags: r

This is the error I get in the console:

> Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘dplyr’ in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]): namespace ‘pillar’ 1.6.1 is already loaded, but >= 1.6.2 is required

Any tips?

Answer (score 1):

Simply try `install.packages("pillar")`. If it doesn't work, try

```
remove.packages("pillar")
install.packages("pillar")

library(pillar)
library(dplyr)
```

If it does not work, after restarting `R`,

```
remove.packages("pillar")
remover.packages("dplyr")
install.packages("pillar")
install.packages("dplyr")

library(pillar)
library(dplyr)
```

Comment: Thank you! The very first option solved the issue: install.packages("pillar"). Is pillar like some core enconding command I must always maintain updated?

Comment: @rapaguayaba Now you update `pillar`, you don't need to update this package every time. Also, this error message may occurs with several other packages. Maybe `ggplot2` will appear too. Then just try this way will help solving the error.